# get previous json item in Json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file titled stuff.json. I am trying to get the previous json item given a certain item. For example, if I am given the key ["also-random-here"], how do I get the previous JSON item "sample-name"?

My JSON data looks as follows:

```
{
    "random-name-here": {
        "name": "name is item1"
    },
    "sample-name": {
        "name": "name is item2"
    },
    "also-random-here": {
        "name": "name is item3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Object.keys()` to convert it to an array. Use `indexOf()` to get the index of the key you want, and subtract 1 to get the previous element.

Comment: `Object.keys(data)` will get the keys in an array, or `Object.entries`

Comment: The notion of order does not exist for the properties, in other words the objects remain the same whatever the combination of the objects which constitute it, and any additional property may be the following property in another instance of your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var names={
    "random-name-here": {
        "name": "name is item1"
    },
    "sample-name": {
        "name": "name is item2"
    },
    "also-random-here": {
        "name": "name is item3"
    }
};
    var prevName= findPrevName(names, "also-random-here") ;

  function findPrevName(item, key) {
      var prevName;
  for (const property in item)
  {
        if(property==key)  break;
       prevName=property;
  };

     return  { [prevName]: item[prevName]};
  };
```